# tqdm.notebook progress bar is not running

Tags: python, tqdm

I am running a model using tqdm.notebook to check the progress using python3.8. However, the progress bar is not running though the generation works okay.

It just shows this on and on.
[image]

Here is my following code, and the model I'm running.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from midi_ddsp.utils.midi_synthesis_utils import synthesize_mono_midi, conditioning_df_to_audio
from midi_ddsp.utils.inference_utils import get_process_group
from midi_ddsp.midi_ddsp_synthesize import load_pretrained_model
from midi_ddsp.data_handling.instrument_name_utils import INST_NAME_TO_ID_DICT
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

# -----MIDI Synthesis-----
midi_file = '/Users/midi-ddsp/midi_example/ode_to_joy.mid'
# Load pre-trained model
synthesis_generator, expression_generator = load_pretrained_model()
# Synthesize with violin:
instrument_name = 'violin'
instrument_id = INST_NAME_TO_ID_DICT[instrument_name]
# Run model prediction
midi_audio, midi_control_params, midi_synth_params, conditioning_df = synthesize_mono_midi(synthesis_generator,
                                                                                           expression_generator,
                                                                                           midi_file, instrument_id,
                                                                                           output_dir=None)

synthesized_audio = midi_audio  # The synthesized audio

conditioning_df_changed = conditioning_df.copy()
```

idk what's the problem. Hope someone can tell me. I appreciate it!

Comment: You don't use `tqdm` anywhere in the code

Comment: @LukaszTracewski, okay, then how to add tqdm in my code?

Comment: I don't know what you wish to measure. What objects do iterate over? Check the `tqdm` docs.